# The rank after adding a rank-one matrix to a full rank matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are all $N$ by $N$ matrices.

$$rank(A) = N, rank(B) = 1$$

What's the lower bound of:  $$rank(A+B)?$$

My guess in this specific case is $$rank(A+B) \geq N-1,$$ but I don't know if it's true, how to prove it, and under what condition we have $rank(A+B) = N-1$.

Can anyone help me with this? I know there is a nice result of the upper bound, $rank(A+B) \leq rank(A) + rank(B)$, but I didn't find anything about the lower bound online.

Comment: This is how I think $rank(A+B) >= N-1$: B can be written as $B = uv^T$, then we can construct a new matrix by adding v^T after the last row of A, and denote this new (N+1) by (N) matrix as A'. Since A is full rank, $rank(A') = N$. Then the effect of (A+B) is like doing elementary row operations for A' by multiplying v^T and then add the the rows of A. This operation will preserve the rank. So after operation $rank(A')=N$. And then we remove the last row of A' then the rank of the rest is at least N-1

Comment: But what I'm more interested in is when $rank(A+B)=N-1$

Answer (score 3):

Think of $A,B$ as linear transformations. $rank(A)=N$ implies $A$ is one to one, hence maps every subspace of dimension $k$ to another subspace of the same dimension. $rank(B)=1$ implies $\dim\ker(B)=N-1$. Now $$\dim(A+B)(\ker(B))=\dim(A(\ker(B)))=\dim(\ker(B))=N-1$$implies $$\dim(Im(A+B))\geq N-1,$$and in other words $$rank(A+B)\geq N-1.$$ Assume now $rank(A+B)=N-1$, so there is $v\neq0$ such that $Av+Bv=0$. Obviously, $A(v)\in Im(B)$, but since $Im(B)$ is $1$-dimensional and $A$ is one to one, $A^{-1}(Im(B))$ is also $1$-dimensional, and actually $A^{-1}(Im(B))=span(v)$. It follows that for *every* $u\in A^{-1}(Im(B)),\;A(u)=-B(u)$.

In conclusion, it is easy to check: Just pick $u\in A^{-1}(Im(B))$ and see whether $A(u)=-B(u)$.

Comment: Thanks! That's a beautiful explanation. But furthermore, do you know when $rank(A+B) = N-1$?

Comment: My thought is, define $\alpha$ such that $B\alpha \in Im(B)$, if $A\alpha + B\alpha = 0$, then $rank(A+B) = N-1$. Otherwise  $rank(A+B) = N$. Am I correct?

Comment: No I think I'm wrong..

Comment: @princeward I extended my answer, have a look.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $rank(X)+rank(Y)\geq rank(X+Y)$, so let $X=A+B$, $Y=-B$, then $rank(A+B)\geq rank(A)-rank(-B)=rank(A)-rank(B)=N-1$